# Error on UpdateWorkflowAssociationsOnChildren()

Tags: workflow, sandbox-solution

I created a sandbox solution that creates following:

- Site Columns
- Content Type with these site columns
- A list based on this content type
- Attaching a workflow to the content type and push it down to the lists based on that content type.

But at this last step it fails.

When i developped it on my local machine it worked perfect, but when I activate the solution on an other sharepoint it fails.

My code:

```
string workflowTemplateName = Resources.ContactFormWorkflowName;
string listTaskName = Resources.WorkflowTasksListName;
string listHistoryName = Resources.WorkflowHistoryListName;

foreach (SPWorkflowTemplate workflowTemplate in web.WorkflowTemplates)
{
   if (workflowTemplate.Name == workflowTemplateName)
   {

      // Create History List
      SPList historylist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listHistoryName);
      if (historylist == null)
      {
         web.Lists.Add(listHistoryName, listHistoryName, SPListTemplateType.WorkflowHistory);
         historylist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listHistoryName);
      }

      // Create Task List
      SPList tasklist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTaskName);
      if (tasklist == null)
      {
         web.Lists.Add(listTaskName, listTaskName, SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
         tasklist = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTaskName);
      }

      SPWorkflowAssociation association = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListContentTypeAssociation(workflowTemplate,
                                                      workflowTemplateName,
                                                      tasklist,
                                                      historylist);

       association.AllowManual = true;
       association.AutoStartCreate = true;
       association.AutoStartChange = false;
       ct.WorkflowAssociations.Add(association);
       ct.Update();
       ct.UpdateWorkflowAssociationsOnChildren();
       ct.Update();
    }
 }
```

If i remove ct.UpdateWorkflowAssociationsOnChildren(); it works, but the workflow is not associated to my list (only the content type).
If i do not remove it, i get the fantastic error:

```
    <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

If I copy the same code in a console sharepoint application, it works... But uploading as a Sandbox WSP it fails.

Complete error:

> Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back. 
>   Feature 'ContactForm.Workflows_Feature1' (ID:
>   '951c4afe-cf8a-4874-afb6-9d4b80119f0b').  Exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException:
>   Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute
>   method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has
>   occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException:
>   0x80070005    Server
>   stack trace:      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.RegisterEventReceiver(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, EventReceiverOperation operation, Guid
>   guidId, String bstrName, Guid guidSiteId, Guid guidWebId, Guid
>   guidHostId, Int32 dwHostType, Int32 dwSynchronization, Int32 dwType,
>   Int32 dwSequenceNumber, String bstrAssembly, String bstrClass, Guid
>   solutionId, String bstrData, String bstrFilter, Int32 dwCredential,
>   Guid contextObjectId, Guid contextType, Guid contextEventType, Guid
>   contextId, Guid contextCollectionId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinition.RegisterForSiteOrWebOrList(Operation
>   operation, Boolean isMigration)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.CreateListSubscription(SPList
>   listElev, Type handlerClass, SPEventReceiverType rt, String filter,
>   String strData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.<>c_*DisplayClass27.b*_24()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.AddAutoStartToList(SPList
>   list, Boolean bCreate, Boolean bChange)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAssociationCollection.AddCore(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   wa, Guid id, SPList list, Boolean forceUtilityListCreation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection.Add(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection_SubsetProxy.Add__Inner(SPWorkflowAssociation_SubsetProxy
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection_SubsetProxy.Add(SPWorkflowAssociation_SubsetProxy
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown
>   at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection_SubsetProxy.Add(SPWorkflowAssociation_SubsetProxy
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection.Add__Inner(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection.Add(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   workflowAssociation)     at
>   Centric.SharePoint.ContactForm.Workflows.ContactFormWorkflow.CreateContactFormWorkflow(SPWeb
>   web, SPContentType ct)     at
>   ContactForm.Workflows.Features.Feature1.Feature1EventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeFeatureCallOutWrapper.ExecuteInternal(Object
>   userCodeObject, SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionContext context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext
>   executionContext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.ExecuteWrapper(SPUserCodeWrapper
>   wrapper, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)    Exception rethrown at [1]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.CodeToExecuteWrapper.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext,
>   Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext,
>   Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext,
>   Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAppDomain.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext,
>   Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxyForShim.ExecuteInternal(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[]
>   proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown
>   at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.ExecuteDelegate.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String currentAffinity,
>   SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodePoolableProcessConnection.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup,
>   Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity,
>   SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken,
>   String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.*PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown
>   at [1]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken,
>   String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext
>   executionContext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type
>   userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext
>   executionContext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.DoSPUserFeatureCallout(SPSite
>   site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureCallOutOperation operation, String
>   solutionHash, String solutionValidatorHash, String
>   solutionValidationErrorUrl, String solutionValidationErrorMessage,
>   String customActionName, IDictionary`2 parameters)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate,
>   Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite
>   siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props,
>   Boolean fForce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed it on an other machine and there works it also fine. Seems that it is an issue typical to that specific environment